# How to control Position of Product Attribute in Grids

Tags: magento2.3.0

I have created a `Product Attribute` called `Local Price` in `Attribute Set` of `Default`, I selected the order so it appears directly above `Price`... which works fine with the edit form...

[image]

However in both the configurations grid on the same edit form and the main product grid it either does not appear or appears in an unexpected place.  I can drag to reorder, but I'd like this to be default behaviour.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by editing `eav_entity_attribute.sort_order` in the database to change the order for each relevant attribute in each attribute set.